# Is there any way to "watch" or "follow" the output of docker-compose ps?

Tags: docker-compose

I've a manifest with a lot of services. They have various start up times. They have simple and health-conditional dependencies on one another. I'd like to watch the output of `docker-compose ps` (obviously, following an `up -d`) until they reach some steady state (like Up, Healthy, or Exited)?

This is only for local testing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

to continuously check the output of a command just use `watch`. For this case:

```
watch -n 1 docker-compose ps
```

Comment: Do you have a Windows equivalent, by any chance? (Ah, I searched, doesn't seem so w/o some nasty scripting loops... no worries)